# Using :not Selector To Remove Margins

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to use the `:not` selector to get rid of margins from an element that isn't followed by a certain element (`.red`).

**HTML**

```
<section class="image"></section>
<div class="red"></div>
<section class="image"></section>
<section class="image"></section>
<section class="image"></section>
```

**CSS**

```
.image {
  background: green;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.image + div:not(.red) {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

For some reason though, the bottom margins aren't being removed. I've setup a CodePen of it in action [over here](http://codepen.io/realph/pen/XJBwmR).

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You cannot use a CSS selector to target a **preceding** element.

Comment: It's really unclear what effect you are after. Do you have a design image?

Comment: @Paulie_D I'm trying to target a following element.

Comment: Ah...OK...it wasn't clear hence my comment.

Comment: @Paulie_D That's okay. I'll update my question to make it a bit clearer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using the sibling selector. Here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9nyvjabx/)

**CSS**:

```
div.red ~ .image {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

This will target any **.image** that is preceded by a **div.red**. However, a **.image** that is before a **div.red** will not be selected.

Comment: I think my original question was worded incorrectly but thanks for this answer anyways, it's really helpful. I've posted an alternate question over here, which better explains what I was trying to achieve. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28884743/add-margin-bottom-to-image-before-footer

Answer (score 0):

```
    .image {
      background: green;
      height: 100px;
      width: 100px;
      margin-bottom: 30px;
    }

    .red .image { //this will select the section which are children of red class and have image class
      margin-bottom: 0;
    }
```