# Add margin-bottom to Image Before footer

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to see if there's a way to add a `margin-bottom` to an `img` element only if it's followed by a `footer` element. At the moment I'm using a special class (`image-before-footer`) on my last `img` element to acheive this, but was wondering if there's a way to do it dynamically in CSS?

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
  <h1>Title goes here</h1>

  <article>Lorem.</article>

  <img src="https://ununsplash.imgix.net/photo-1421284621639-884f4129b61d?dpr=1.80&fit=crop&fm=jpg&h=700&q=75&w=1050"/>

  <article>Lorem.</article>

  <img class="image-before-footer" src="https://ununsplash.imgix.net/photo-1421284621639-884f4129b61d?dpr=1.80&fit=crop&fm=jpg&h=700&q=75&w=1050"/>

  <footer class="footer">
    <p>Here are my footnotes</p>
  </footer>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
article {
  margin: 3em 0;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin: 0;
}

.image-before-footer {
  margin-bottom: 3em;
}
```

Any help with this is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think the below solutions is the best option. img + footer {
  margin-top: 3em;
}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you can't select previous sibling elements in CSS, why not just add a `margin-top` to the `footer` element *if* it follows an `img` element using the [adjacent sibling combinator, `+`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#adjacent-sibling-combinators):

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/g1y19msm/)

```
img + footer {
  margin-top: 3em;
}
```

---

You could also just select the *last* `img` element using the [`:last-of-type` pseudo class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:last-of-type).

Of course, this assumes that the last `img` element will be succeeded by the `footer`, though.

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/Lj5t1fg4/)

```
img:last-of-type {
    margin-bottom: 3em;
}
```

Comment: Sounds like a great solution! I'll give it a shot when I'm back home.

Answer (score 1):

You can use adjacent sibling selector for that. It will select only the specified element that immediately follows the former specified element.

```
former_element + target_element { style properties }
```

Base on your code, the syntax would be:

```
img + footer {
    margin-top: 3em;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you could try last-of-type pseudo element:

```
img:last-of-type {
margin-bottom: 3em;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

http://jsfiddle.net/isqware/g4hxw97m/

HTML

```
<div class="container">
<h1>Title goes here</h1>
<article>Lorem.</article>
<img src="https://ununsplash.imgix.net/photo-1421284621639-884f4129b61d?dpr=1.80&fit=crop&fm=jpg&h=700&q=75&w=1050"/>
<article>Lorem.</article>
<img class="" src="https://ununsplash.imgix.net/photo-1421284621639-884f4129b61d?dpr=1.80&fit=crop&fm=jpg&h=700&q=75&w=1050"/>
<footer class="footer">
<p>Here are my footnotes</p>
</footer>
</div>
```

CSS

```
article {
margin: 3em 0;
}

img {
width: 100%;
vertical-align: middle;
margin: 0;
}

.image-before-footer {
 margin-bottom: 3em;
} 
.footer{
background:#000;
width:100%;
min-height:100px;
}
```

Jquery

```
$( "footer.footer" ).prev('img').addClass( "image-before-footer" );
```

I hope it works. Check the JSFiddle example.

Cheers